# How to change keyboard language in SwiftUI by wrapping UITextField and using UITextInputMode

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uitextfield

When I wanted to change the keyboard language in my UIKit app, I would use the following code:

```
import UIKit

class WordTextField: UITextField {

    var language: String? {
        didSet {
            if self.isFirstResponder{
                self.resignFirstResponder()
                self.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
        
    override var textInputMode: UITextInputMode? {
        if let language = self.language {
            for inputMode in UITextInputMode.activeInputModes {
                if let inputModeLanguage = inputMode.primaryLanguage, inputModeLanguage == language {
                    return inputMode
                }
            }
        }
        return super.textInputMode
    }
}
```

I would call it like so:

```
foreignWord.language = changeKeyboard.currentKeyboardLanguage(currentLanguage: currentLanguageName)
```

Where foreignWord is class WordTextField and currentLanguageName would be a string like: "German". The .currentKeyboardLanguage(:) method returns a BCP code string, like:

"de-DE"

for German, which is assigned to the language property in the WordTextField class.

This works fine in UIKit, but there doesn't seem to be any native support for changing keyboard language in SwiftUI.

How would I write a SwiftUI wrapper for WordTextField, so I can assign a BCP code to it's language property.

I would need any solution to support the focus modifier, so the keyboard can be shown and dismissed programatically.